# Sending sms through asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I want to send sms through asp.net web page.  Could any body give me code (vb.net) and some info. how to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: It depends whose service you are going to use for sending SMS. There are different protocols for sending SMS so there are different code.

Comment: Itdepends how to send SMS..  Two ways.. SMPP gateway or HTTP Gateway.. Depends how you want to send & you is smpp provider

Comment: Please find google then ask here

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here for Example on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/318471/Sending-Sms-Using-Asp-net)

Itdepends how to send SMS.. Two ways.. SMPP gateway or HTTP Gateway.. Depends how you want to send & you is smpp provider

If you are and end application you can connect smpp server (which costs less for bulk sms provider or GSM service provider)

So you become SMPP (or esme) client which connects to SMPP (or esme) Server.

SMPP/ESME/HTTP client you can code or can download for free.. but the SMPP/ESME/HTTP server may cost you for some bucks for bulk sms

Comment: Can u recommend any free gateways?  I do not mind if it is HTTP or SMPP.

Comment: You mean I should ask my mobile service provider for the required code and use that in my asp.net page?

Comment: mobile service provider or ems service provider will give you a short code and username password and configurational stuff like ton npi retry timeout etc etc